# Why when I have only 1 export default in the file, it still doesn't export?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, react-native

I don't get why I keep receiving an error like this:

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

```
import React, {
  useEffect
} from 'react';
import Tmdb from './Tmdb';

export default () => {

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadAll = async () => {
      // Pegar a Lista Total
      let list = await Tmdb.getHomeList();
      console.log(list);
    }

    loadAll();
  }, []);

  return (
     <div>
    Hello World!
    </div>
  );
  

}
```

Comment: You should check that what you're requesting is JSON because it doesn't look like it. Use your browser dev tools to check for errors in the console/network tabs.

Comment: How is this related to importing/exporting?

Answer (score -1):

the JSON at the start of the code has to have a variable to set on like this: `{"example":useEffect}`

**And remember to add quotations in the html code, it could mess up the code.**